# Linux command select specific directory

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have only two folders under a given directory. Is there any method to choose the second directory based on the order and not on the folder name?

Example: (**I want to enter under doc2**)

```
#ls
doc1  doc2
```

Comment: `-s` will sort by size, `-r` will reverse the order, other then that you will need to pipe it into another command to sort it.  What is the criteria that you want to sort the folders by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tail command to get the last line
ls |tail -1

Comment: Thanks BUT I want to enter under this directory

Comment: cd "$(ls -1|tail -1)" will enter the dir. But as said before is an bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `ls`,

```
cd "$(ls -d */ | sed -n '2p')"
```

selects enters the second directory listed by it, independently of the number of directories provided by `ls`.

[Parsing `ls` output is not a good idea generally](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), although it will work in most cases and will cause no harm if you are just using it in your interactive shell for fast navigation. You **should not** use this for serious programming.